# Distribution of interaction energy in electrostatic systems

Tags: electrostatics, energy, electric-fields, charge, potential-energy

If we have two electrostatic systems their interaction energy is given by
$$U=\epsilon_0\int\vec E_1\cdot\vec E_2dV\equiv\int\rho_1\phi_2dV\equiv\int\rho_2\phi_1dV$$ Here the integral is over the whole space .
The question is how is this energy stored? I am not asking if the energy is in fields or the particles.

If we assume that energy is in fields then is half of $\epsilon_0\int\vec E_1\cdot\vec E_2dV$ in $\vec E_1$ and other half in $\vec E_2$?

Or in the particle model half in one system's charges and other half in other's?  That is, $U=(1/2)(\int\rho_1\phi_2dV+\int\rho_2\phi_1dV)$?

But in the particle model, we can even say that $U=\frac1{m+n}(m\int\rho_1\phi_2dV+n\int\rho_2\phi_1dV)$, for any numbers $m,n$, even negatives.

As an example consider a system made of linear dielectric and some free charge density, the net energy can be expressed as
$$U=\frac12\int\rho\phi dV =\frac12 \bigg(\int\rho_f\phi dV+\int\rho_b\phi dV\bigg)$$
Since net charge density is simply the sum of free charge density and bound charge density, and $\phi$ is the net potential created by both charge densities.

This then can be shown to be equal to (again integrals are over the whole space):
$$U=\frac12\bigg(\int\vec E\cdot\vec DdV+\int\rho_b\phi dV\bigg)$$
Here the first term is the energy one considers when talking about dielectric materials, the work done on free charge, which is usually derived by changing the free charge density and evaluating the work integral
$$\Delta U_f = \int\Delta\rho_f\phi dV\rightarrow U_f=\frac12\int\vec E\cdot\vec DdV $$

Thus above analysis seem to indicate that in the case of linear dielectrics the interaction energy is distributed equally within the two systems.
But is this a general result or just a coincidence, special case for the general answer?

How is energy distributed among the systems?

Comment: Your first equation is incorrect; $U\propto \int dV \vec{E} \cdot \vec{E}$. The two factors of the electric field in the dot product are the same. An algorithm for computing the energy would be to visit each tiny volume element in space, square the magnitude of the electric field in that volume element, multiply by the volume of the volume element, and sum the result over all the volume elements in all of space (up to some normalization factor, which isn't relevant for this question).

Comment: @Andrew $dU/dV =0.5E^2=0.5(\vec E_1+\vec E_2)^2=0.5E_1^2+0.5E_2^2+E1\cdot E_2$. This third term is what I am talking about, also I was working in HL system but I'll edit to SI.

Comment: @Andrew also it's perfectly fine to talk about total field E rather than $E_1$ and $ E_2$ as I am doing, but in doing so we have to ask the question of distribution of $0.5\int E^2dV$, but if we split the field in two parts as I did then then question becomes more concentrated and to the point, asking only about interaction energy's distribution

Comment: I see. I don't think your question has an answer. The only thing we can measure is the total energy of the system or the total energy density in a volume element. What experiment would you do to distinguish different possible answer to your question?

Comment: @Andrew At the moment I have no answer to your question, but as motivation for asking the question I asked, check out this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/724722/330899. Here the Answerer used the model in which energy is equally distributed within the two systems and got to the same result one gets without making such assumptions. So it kind of points in the direction that energy is distributed equally but then again maybe this is just a very special case.

Answer (score 2):

Electrostatic energy is always associated with some system of particles, and *can be regarded* as distributed in space. It is not usual to consider it distributed among material parts of the system only; when we consider it distributed in space, usually some of it is distributed also in vacuum, where no part of the system is present.

Consider electrostatic energy of two point-like charged particles:
$$
W_{pair} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{q_1q_2}{r_{12}}.
$$

You seem to be asking, how much of this energy "belongs to the particle 1"?

Standard theory does not answer this question, and maybe the question itself is "the wrong question".

EM energy can be expressed as integral of energy density over the whole space, in this case of two point particles, we have
$$
W_{pair} = \int_{whole~space} \epsilon_0\mathbf E_1 \cdot \mathbf E_2 ~dV,
$$
where $\mathbf E_1,\mathbf E_2$ are the electrostatic fields of the first and second particle.

We can see in this integral that there is some contribution to system's EM energy coming from the space region where the first particle is, another from the space region where the second particle is, *and another from the rest of the space, where the system is not present*. If the region associated with the first particle is shrinked to a point where the particle is, contribution of this region becomes zero, and then all energy energy is stored in spatial points where the first particle is not present. Similarly for the second particle.

Of course, this density $\epsilon_0\mathbf E_1\cdot \mathbf E_2$ is not the only possible density giving the correct result. But it is the simplest and the most natural one, and it associates some EM energy with empty space, where the system *is not located*.

It may be useful, to remember the electrostatic energy formula for system of point-like particles
$$
W = \sum_{kk'}{}^{'} \frac{1}{2} q_k \varphi_{k'}(\mathbf r_k),
$$
to think as if energy is sum of contributions stored in each particle, and any single contribution depends on all other particles.

But this works only for electrostatic energy. As soon as the particles move and we have magnetic fields present, the above formula becomes inaccurate for total system EM energy. The accurate formula involves magnetic fields and integrating over the whole space, so we come back to the idea that part of the energy is also present in empty vacuum, far away from the charged particles, so the system energy is not easily partitionable to charged particles only; some of it, possibly all of it, is associated with the space far from the particles.

Comment: Is $\varphi_k'$ potential over here? Because if yes then why is the factor of $1/4\pi\epsilon_0$ coming? Also, *to think as if energy is sum of contributions stored in each particle*, as I mentioned in the post this is not a unique argument since it works for any numbers $m,n$, and not just 1/2.

Comment: Right, I've removed that factor. Also, that was not an argument I defend, it was an explanation for why energy is sometimes thought of as sum over particles. I do not think there is a good argument for that being the best/preferred view on partition of EM energy. We can equally well view it as partitioned over all pairs of particles. Or ignore any possible assignment of energy to individual particles or groups of particles, and just regard it as distributed in space.

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is false, the whole energy of the field-particle system is represented by **either** the energy of the field **or** by the Coulomb energy. It is not split between field and particles.
In fact, the energy in the field and the Coulomb electric potential energy of interaction between particles are just the same. Thus, what is called potential energy is stored into the field.

**Proof**

The energy of the field-particle system is given by:

$$ H= \sum_{ \alpha } \frac{1}{2} m_{ \alpha } V_{ \alpha }^{2}(t)+ \frac{ \varepsilon _{0}}{2}  \int  E^{2}( \overrightarrow{r},t) + c^{2}B^{2}( \overrightarrow{r},t) d^{3}r $$

In the static case, without external magnetic field, it reduces to:
$$H=  \frac{ \varepsilon _{0}}{2}  \int  E^{2}( \overrightarrow{r})  d^{3}r  $$

At this point, the whole energy of the system is just contained into the field.

Using the Parseval formula, we get:

$$H=  \frac{ \varepsilon _{0}}{2}  \int  E^{2}( \overrightarrow{r},t)  d^{3}r=  \frac{ \varepsilon _{0}}{2}  \int   \overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}} ^{*}(\overrightarrow{k}). \overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}} (\overrightarrow{k})  d^{3}k   $$

Decompose the fields into a parallel and perpendicular component:

$$\overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}} =\overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}}_{  /  / }+\overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E} _{ \bot } }$$

with:
$$\begin{cases}{\overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}}_{  /  / }. \overrightarrow{k}=k\mathscr{ E}}_{  /  / } \\\overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}}_{  \bot  }.\overrightarrow{k}=0\end{cases}$$

The energy of the system fields-particles now reads:
$$H= \frac{ \varepsilon _{0}}{2}  \int    | \overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}_{ /  / }}(\overrightarrow{k}) | ^{2}   d^{3}k +\frac{ \varepsilon _{0}}{2}  \int    | \overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}_{ \bot  }}(\overrightarrow{k}) | ^{2}   d^{3}k$$

To keep going, we need the Fourier transform of Maxwell's equations. In the static case, we only have:

$$\begin{cases}   \overrightarrow{ \nabla }. \overrightarrow{E}( \overrightarrow{r}) = \frac{ \rho( \overrightarrow{r}) }{ \varepsilon _{0}}   \\ \overrightarrow{ \nabla }  \times  \overrightarrow{E}( \overrightarrow{r}) = \overrightarrow{0}  \end{cases}  ~~  \Longleftrightarrow ~~\begin{cases}k. \overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}_{ /  / }}= \frac{ \varrho (k)}{\varepsilon _{0}} \\ \overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}_{ \bot  }}= \overrightarrow{0} \end{cases}  $$

The charge distribution and its Fourier transform are given by:

$$ \rho ( \overrightarrow{r})= \sum_{ \alpha }q_{ \alpha }~ \delta ( \overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r_{ \alpha }} )  $$

$$  \rho ( \overrightarrow{r})= \sum_{ \alpha }q_{ \alpha }~ \delta ( \overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r_{ \alpha }} )   \Longleftrightarrow ~~ \rho ( \overrightarrow{k})= \frac{1}{(2 \pi )^{3}}  \sum_{ \alpha }q_{ \alpha }~e^{-i~\overrightarrow{k}.\overrightarrow{r_{ \alpha }}}$$

Combining all these results, we get:

$$\overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}}_{ /  / }( \overrightarrow{k})= -\frac{i}{ \varepsilon _{0}}  \rho ( \overrightarrow{k}) \frac{ \overrightarrow{k} }{k^{2}}= -\frac{i}{(2 \pi )^{3} \varepsilon _{0}}  \sum_{ \alpha }q_{ \alpha }~e^{-i~\overrightarrow{k}.\overrightarrow{r_{ \alpha }}} \frac{ \overrightarrow{k} }{k^{2}}$$

And for the energy:

$$H= \frac{ \varepsilon _{0}}{2}  \int    | \overrightarrow{\mathscr{ E}_{ /  / }}(\overrightarrow{k}) | ^{2}   d^{3}k= \sum_{ \alpha } \frac{q^{2}_{ \alpha }}{2(2 \pi )^{3} \varepsilon _{0}}  \int  \frac{d^{3}k}{k^{2}}  + \sum_{ \alpha  \neq  \beta } \frac{q_{ \alpha }q_{ \beta }}{2(2 \pi )^{3} \varepsilon _{0}}   \int d^{3}k \frac{e^{-i~\overrightarrow{k}.(\overrightarrow{r_{ \alpha }}-\overrightarrow{r_{ \beta }})} }{k^{2}}$$

The first integral:$\int  \frac{d^{3}k}{k^{2}}$ diverges and needs a cutoff (shortcoming of classical electrodynamics). It generates a term called self energy.

Inverting the Fourier transform, one gets:

$$ H= \sum_{ \alpha }  \varepsilon ^{ \alpha }_{coulomb}   + \frac{1}{8 \pi  \varepsilon _{0}} \sum_{ \alpha  \neq  \beta } \frac{q_{ \alpha }q_{ \beta }}{| \overrightarrow{r_{ \alpha }}-\overrightarrow{r_{ \beta }} |} $$

Now, the whole energy of the field-particle system is the Coulomb energy. The energy in the field and the electric potential energy of interaction between particles are thus just the same.

How is the potential energy stored is a tricky question. Since both the potential energy and field energy are equal, and since the particles are not physically changed by moving from infinity to their final position, one can only conclude that the field stores the energy .